# Set apache log folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, logging

I have a home server with debian as S.O. and apache/php7 installed

Like web hosting have error.log on root folder, I want a similar solution for each website that I have on my /www folder instead of single file that for default is "var/log/apache2/error.log"

I'm trying to working on htaccess adding this line

```
RewriteEngine On RewriteLog "path/to/error.log" RewriteLogLevel 9
```

but not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put a RewriteLog directive in an .htaccess. This is available in the server config or virtual host config only.

- [mod_rewrite doc - rewritelog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog)

**example for vhost:**

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/yoursite.com.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteLog /var/log/apache2/rewrite.log
    RewriteLogLevel 9
  </IfModule>
  ServerName yoursite.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/yoursite/html
  <Directory "/var/www/yoursite/html">
      <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
      </IfModule>
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**example for all sites on your server (global):**

create file like `/etc/apache2/conf-available/debug.conf`

add your configuration here:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteLog /var/log/apache2/rewrite.log
  RewriteLogLevel 9
</IfModule>
```

enable the config:

`sudo a2enconf debug ; sudo service apache2 reload`

disable the config:

`sudo a2disconf debug ; sudo service apache2 reload`

Comment: Ok, but to create error.log for each "/var/www/site/html" I must create conf file for each site?